# How to locate the element as per the HTML through FindElementByXPath in Selenium Basic

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm writing a VBA code to login into a webpage and load some information i have in an excel worksheet.

I'm new in Selenium. I already got the login part right, but now i need to click in an element and i keep getting errors.

I need to click in the `Company 2` button.

[image: Example of the page]

This is what i've got so far:

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value=""Company 1""]").Click
```

Outputs `NoSuchElementError`

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value=""Company 2""]").Click
```

Outputs `ElementNotVisible`

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, i think that the first input being hidden has something to do. Hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Might help you to know you can also use `ByCss` in most circumstances, in which case you can use:

```
bot.FindElementByCss("input[value='Company 1']").Click
```

That is nice and short.

The [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) is `input[value='Company 1']`. This says find element with `input` tag having attribute `value` with value of `'Company 1'`.

Comment: Selectors are less prone to break as they are very specific. Your one seem promising.

Comment: Hi @SIM. Nice to see you. A little simplistic but you might enjoy 5 minutes on the following: https://flukeout.github.io/   32 levels. See how you score :-) Just read the right hand side first - which I forgot to do!

Comment: Hi QHarr, unluckily that didn't resolve the issue. I think it has something to do with the previous input being hidden.

`input[value='Company 1'] -> NuSuchElementError`
`input[value='Company 2'] -> ElementNotVisibleError`

Comment: Can you try looping until visible? It may be beyond the implicit selenium wait time?

Comment: I had a 10sec before that line. I can see the button but i keep getting `ElementNotVisibleError` --- Is there a possiblity that the first input that is hidden has something to do?

Comment: Are there any events/javascripts attached?

Comment: I dont really know, I'm mostly a newbie. Can you tell me how can i know?

Comment: Sorry. I can actually see that there are. You might want to inspect the page and have a look at what those javascript functions do.

Comment: I think i found the function: $(function(){$('input.btn_empresa').button();});

Answer (score 0):

XPath might be incorrect. Please try the following syntax:

```
FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='Company 1']")
```

Comment: Hi rajeshkt, thanks. But i keep getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use CSS selectors whenever possible. They are much easier to handle.
Now if you are using CSS selectors try to find the second button using something like

`input[value="Company 2"]`

For more info on this selector, look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use any xpath, in first look I found your xpath is incorrect, try this:

```
//input[@type='button'][@value='Company 2']
//input[@type='button'&& @value='Company 2']
//input[@role='button'][@value='Company 2']
```

You can also use `findelements()` to store are all buttons and using if else you can extract the company 2 button

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to invoke `click()` on the desired elements you can use the following solution:

- To click on the element with text as **Company 1**:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='btn_empresa ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all' and @value='Company 1']").Click
  ```
- To click on the element with text as **Company 2**:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='btn_empresa ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all' and @value='Company 2']").Click
  ```

Comment: Hi! In both cases i get NoSuchElementError. I think it has something to do with the first input being hidden

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking the HTML in inspect and going to Copy>Copy XPath? That might give you something different. Maybe the buttons are created from Javascript and so the WebDriver can't actually see them?

Or try

```
Company_1 = bot.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Company 1']")
Company_1.click()

Company_2 = bot.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Company 2']")
Company_2.click()
```

And change the syntax with the ' ' quotes like someone else mentioned.

Comment: Hi Grim, how can i tell if the buttons are created from javascript? And is there a way i could click on them if so?